What is the "score" refering to in the Top Users page of a tag?
I stumbled across the Top Users Page of the android-jetpack-compose tag. I took a look into the ranking for the last 30 days, which looks like this:

Now, when looking into Thracian's entry, it says a score of 34. However, after looking into their answers, there are three accepted answer within the last week, which already would lead to a reputation by at least 45 (not even counting in the upvotes). Below answer alone already resulted in 55 reputation:

Thus I am wondering what the "score" actually is referring to? Is it the number of upvotes? If so, why are accepted answers not taken into consideration? What am I missing here?

Relevant (maybe duplicate?): How are tag scores calculated? | What is the meaning of 'Score' on the Stack Overflow Tags statistics page?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-top-users-page-calculated

Score <> Reputation.
The score is the number between the up and down vote buttons of the post, and is simply upvotes - downvotes; so your post here as a score of 0 at the time I am writing. The post your screenshot is of has a score of 4 (4 (upvotes) - 0 (downvotes)).
Reputation is awarded to users to a variety of reasons, such as (but not limited to) receiving a up vote on a post (10 reputation), receiving a downvote (-2 reputation), answer accepted (15 reputation), suggested edit approved (2 reputation).
The Score here is a sum of votes on content the user has received on answers that they have posted in the last 30 days related to the tag you are viewing. So, if the user posted 2 answers, and received 5 upvotes and 2 downvotes, their score would be 3. Accepted answers do not come into it; "acceptance" isn't a "super upvote".
